# Reaching 0 K in a "Finite number of steps"

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, low-temperature-physics

Let me preface this by saying that I don't really like the third law of thermodynamics very much.

Its not that I believe its not true, its just that it feels non rigorous, all its different formulations seem very different to me and its not obvious to me how to derive one from the other.

This question concerns a specific formulation that doesn't mention entropy at all. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics), a classic formulation of the third law by Nernst is that

> It is impossible for any process, no matter how idealized, to reduce
>   the entropy of a system to its absolute-zero value in a finite number
>   of operations.

This formulation seems to come from:

> Nernst, W. Sitzber. Kgl. Preuss. Akad. Wiss. Physik-Math. Kl. 134
>   (1912)

which unfortunately I could never find (wikipedia cites [a thermodynamics book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/physical-chemistry-an-advanced-treatise/jost/978-0-12-245601-5) for their statement).

This statement of the third law (or consequence of the third law?) seems to be widespread, however, I have never understood what "finite number of operations means". This seems like the only place in thermodynamics where this "finite number of operations" concept its invoked, and I don't see how it can be defined even in an informal way.

My question is: what is the mathematics behind this? Is there a more formal statement of this version of the third law? [Callen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471862568), for example, says that "finite number of operations" = "adiabatic reversible process" (last paragraph on the chapter on the third law), but I can't really see why.

Comment: PS: If someone knows where I can find a translation of Nernst's paper I'd love to get it.